# VoiceOver Page Announcement is Incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

With VoiceOver turned on, the current page is announced when the user scrolls by swiping with three fingers, e.g: "Page 1 of 3". However, these announcements are not always correct.

The following code creates a scroll view and populates it with three labels (with different background colours to differentiate them):

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.frame = view.bounds
view.addSubview(scrollView)

let colours: [UIColor] = [.red, .blue, .green]
var lastView: UIView?

for colour in colours {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
    label.backgroundColor = colour
    label.textColor = .white
    label.text = "\(colours.firstIndex(of: colour)!)"
    label.textAlignment = .center

    scrollView.addSubview(label)

    label.frame.origin.y = lastView?.frame.maxY ?? 0

    lastView = label
}

scrollView.contentSize.height = lastView!.frame.maxY
```

When I scroll (as explained above), the following announcements are made:

- Page 1 of 4
- Page 2 of 4
- Page 4 of 4
- Page 4 of 4

**Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this a bug in iOS? If it is the latter, is there any workaround I can apply to ensure the correct page numbers are announced?**

Comment: Your code snippet only shows 3 colored labels (0, 1 and 2) with a one-finger swipe: 'page x of y' can't be read out this way. Why don't you use a UIPageViewController to reach your goal ?

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted my question. I have a scrollview it works fine. My issue is only when VoiceOver mode is enabled. If you run my code (put it in viewDidLoad), enable VoiceOver and scroll (with a 3 finger swipe), it should be clear.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned in your comment, I misunderstood your problem.

> Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this a bug in iOS?

**You're doing nothing wrong**: the system calculates the total amount of pages necessary to scroll the content with a three-finger vertical swipe and it doesn't have to match your label's number.

Take a look at the displayed colored label provided by your code hereunder:
[image]
Each swipe doesn't display a label on its entire height and width, that's why you have more pages than label amount: that's definitely not a bug, **that's the way it works**.

> ... is there any workaround I can apply to ensure the correct page numbers are announced?

However, if that's what you're willing to reach, I suggest to take a look at the [custom scrolling](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html#CustomScrolling) that might help *(I never used it but that's the only line of inquiry I see for your goal)*.

So, unfortunately **no workaround** for the problem you mentioned because it often happens even for the native iOS apps.

See the most right-hand page on your iPhone with the widgets and listen the page numbers that are announced: the first announcement is always wrong for me *(5 pages while there are only 3)*.

The first announcement/reading is sometimes wrong but after some three-finger vertical swipes, the system corrects its initial error as I pointed out with my illustration.

That's not a perfect situation for the user but, for now, **you can't do anything better** unless lighting a candle for a very soon fix of this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer! Unfortunately, my issue is not that the number of pages doesn’t match the label, it’s that “Page 4 of 4” is announced for both the 3rd and 4th pages. Sorry, I should have made this clearer in my question. Does this issue not occur for you when you run my code?

Comment: You don't hear 'page 3 of 4' only during the first complete vertical swipes but it works when you come back (that's what I showed up with illustrations). There's definitely a slight but obvious problem as mentioned: write a radar to Apple maybe because that should be working automatically